# How can take ref parameter using Invoke with Reflection

Tags: reflection, parameter-passing, invoke, ref

How can take ref parameter(OutputData) using Invoke with Reflection.
objectValues is an object array  that take an parameters is sending parameter to "FM_DEC_ENC" Method.This method contains 8 parameter. One of them is outputData re parameter

```
 mInfo.Invoke("FM_DEC_ENC", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                 null, objectValues,null)
```

---

```
public Int32 FM_DEC_ENC(String AdapterID, String SlotID, String InputData, 
        String DecKeyName, String EncKeyName, HsmCommConstants.ENCRIPTION DecEcbOrCbc,
        HsmCommConstants.ENCRIPTION EncEcbOrCbc, ref String OutputData)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already doing it correctly by keeping a reference to the parameter array. When the method returns, the result will be in `objectValues[7]`.

Note that this won't work if `FM_DEC_ENC` is a native method that expects a modifiable buffer as `OutputData` (because `System.String` cannot be modified). In this case, [you can also specify StringBuilder as parameter type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor3).